# No se como resolver este problema con closures

Tags: javascript

Buen dia, tengo este problema que necesito resolver con un closure, no me sale y no se que estoy declarando mal

Closures

Enunciado:

Implementar la función telefonoDescompuesto que recibe una cadena y que debe devolver otra función que devuelva las consonantes de la cadena Si el parámetro es igual a nulo o indefinido debería devolver falso

```
function telefonoDescompuesto(string) {
  function quitarvocales(string){ 
    return function(){ 
      if(typeof string !== 'string'){
        return "string debe ser una cadena de texto"
      }
      var sinVocales = string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, "")
      return sinVocales
    }
  }
}
var cons = quitarvocales("cadena")
```

**La terminal me arroja este error**:

```
sinVocales = string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, "") 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
```

Tambien probe colocando una verificacion type of para string

```
function quitarvocales(string){ 
  if(typeof string !== 'string'){
    return "string debe ser una cadena de texto"
  }
  return function(){
    var sinVocales = string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, "")
    return sinVocales
  }
}
var cons = quitarvocales()
console.log(cons("cadena"))
```

**Este fue el error que me dio la terminal**

```
console.log(cons("cadena")) 
^ TypeError: cons is not a function
```

Si podrian ayudarme a entender como funciona este cierre

Comment: Ya casi lo tenés, los detalles que te faltan son mínimos. Acá te dejo [las correcciones](https://playcode.io/907782). Mi duda (y por lo que no agregué respuesta) es si quien tiene que devolver `false` es la función que devuelves o la función `telefonoDescompuesto`.

Comment: Excelente muchas, gracias ya me salio

Comment: Pon en el título _el problema en cuestión_ y en la respuesta _cómo resolviste el problema_. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tal respuesta. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, lee [ask] y [answer].